# Check if user entered both a first and last name

Tags: java, string, int, indexof

I'm making a program that gives random lottery numbers to inputted names. The problem though is that I have to make sure the user entered both a first and last name. I'm using a method of finding the space in the users input, then creating substrings from that data, but I keep on getting the error "incompatible type" right under my for loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
enter code here
import java.util.Scanner;      //Import scanner class
import java.util.Random;       //Import random number generator
import java.io.*;              //Import PrintWriter

public class Lab4ZinkovskyFl   //Program that lets user enter a name and generates random lottery numbers for that name
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

Random randomNumbers = new Random();

String again = "y";                      //Control the loop
int r1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(100)+ 1;  //*******************
int r2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(100)+ 1;  //*   Random lottery  
int r3 = randomNumbers.nextInt(100)+ 1;  //*   numbers for    
int r4 = randomNumbers.nextInt(100)+ 1;  //*   program        
int r5 = randomNumbers.nextInt(100)+ 1;  //******************* 

    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"))  // Allows the user to continue the loop
    {
        System.out.println ("Please enter first and last name to enter the lottery.");
        String fullName = keyboard.nextLine();

        boolean space = false;  // Checks for first and last name       

        for (int i = 0; i < fullName.length(); i++)
        {       
            if (fullName.indexOf(i) == " ")
            {
                space = true;
                spaceIndex = i;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println ("Error, please enter both first and last name to continue.");
            }

        }
    String firstName = fullName.substring (0, spaceIndex);
    String lastName = fullName.substring (spaceIndex, fullName.length());

    System.out.println (lastName + ", " + firstName + ": " + r1 + ", " + r2 + ", " + r3 + ", " + r4 + ", " + r5);


    System.out.println ("Run the lottery again? (y=yes)");
    again = keyboard.nextLine();
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the user input by " ", like this:

```
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
```

And then you create a method to return true if the user do enters the full name.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    if (names[i].trim().equals("")) {
        names[i] = null;
    }
}
int elementsWithText = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    if (names[i] != null) {
        elementsWithText++;
    }
}

return elementsWithText == 2;
```

Something like that. Hopefully you figure what I am doing. If you don't know what the methods calls are doing, they are all from `String`. Here is the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() takes in a char as input (in your case). Change i to " "(space)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write like this

```
  if (fullName.indexOf(" ") == -1) 
   {
     System.out.println ("Error, please enter both first and last name to continue.");
   }
   else 
   {
     space = true;
     spaceIndex = i;
   }
```

But why you choose for loop?

@sweeper has given the best solution.